# Limit same password in password change

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I’m building a gui on python with tkinter, i’ve made a login, register and change password screens, hosting the data on mysql, i want to make an option that if user already choose password “x” for example, he will be able to repeat the password only 1 more time, after that it will not give him an option to choose and repeat the same password on the change password screen, any clue how to do it?

Comment: You could add a column to your user table which keeps track of the number of times they've used their current password, or you could use another table with a foreign-key relationship to the user table to do the same if you don't want to pollute your user table.

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick response, i also think about tracking the password, but how would u do it in code? In saving the passwords as salt+hash

Comment: You extract the salt from the current password and re-compute the new password hash with the prior salt. If it matches the old salt+hash, then they've used the same password. Keep in mind that you will have to keep track of all salt+hash history in a separate table otherwise it only works for consecutive password changes.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of your user's salt+hash combinations in another table and compute their new hash using old salts to make sure they've never tried to use it before.

An example...

Let's say your user's password history is in a list of dicts:

```py
password_history = [
  {
    "salt": "89!$@sg",
    "hash": "asdfjhlaksjdhflkjahsdlkfjh",
  },
]

def has_used_password(password_history, new_password):
  hashes = set(h["hash"] for h in password_history)

  count = 0
  for entry in password_history:
    hash_with_old_salt = hash_password(new_password, entry["salt"])
    if hash_with_old_salt in hashes :
      count += 1
  return count
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, but I'm saving the pass as random salt+hash in the same column, I have tried to decrypt the old pass to check against the new pass.. but I think it's not a good way and not secured

Comment: Well I do not recommend trying to decrypt old passwords. Think of how your application actually checks for a password match. It takes the password a user entered, combines it with their existing salt, hashes it, and checks if it matches the stored hash. If it's a match, they've entered the correct password and they can login, otherwise not. We are using that same strategy. Compute a potential new hash for the password they've entered by calculating new hashes from old salts. If the potentially new hash matches any of the old hashes, you've got a collision. This method is not insecure.

Comment: Maybe private messages would be a better way to proceed.

Comment: Hey thanks alot again! there is not an private message option here..any other way to contact?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with (user, passwords_used) as columns. Each time a user changes their password, check it against this table. If that (user, password) pair isn't in the table, add it to the table and change the password. Otherwise reject it as reused.